# Django model select choice, populated with fields from other model instances

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

Suppose I have a model Car that has a field brand and a model owner that has two field: name and car_brand, whereas the latter should be one of the Car instances brands. I need to have a form where the user is presented with a text field name and a drop down select choice populated with all the brand name of Car instances. How would I achieve that?

Here is the code I am starting with. Feel free to correct. Thanks.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    car_brand = models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Select
from app.models import Owner

class OwnerForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Owner
        fields = ("name", "car_brand")
        widgets = {
            "name" : TextInput(attrs={"class" : "name"}),
            "car_brand" : Select(attrs={"class" : "car_brand"}),
        }
```

Comment: Why have you overridden the widgets? The default model form would have given you exactly what you wanted.

Comment: I need to define class attributes for each field.

Comment: Another question is: how does it know to pick the "brand" field from Car for choices when models.ForeignKey(Car) does not specify what field to pick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just define a `__unicode__` method on your `Car` model and I think it should work fine.  As Daniel mentioned, the form might be getting confused since you've overridden the widgets.  I could be wrong, but I thought django automatically rendered attributes on form elements that can be used for styling purposes.  Maybe you don't need to override the widgets.  If not, you can specify the form field explicitly:

```
class OwnerForm(ModelForm):
    car_brand = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Car.objects.all(),
        widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'car_brand'}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Owner
        fields = ('name', 'car_brand')
        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'name'})
        }
```

As a side note, is there any reason you don't have a `CarBrand` model and a foreign key field relating the `Car` model to it?  That would be a more normalized approach to modeling your data.

Comment: Thanks. Why would I need another model in the middle? Right now I have the relationship Owner-Car. With additional model I will have Owner-Car-CarBrand. What would be the advantage of doing that?

Comment: The advantage is that you don't duplicate data in the Car.brand field.  With the Car model defined in that way, people can put anything they want in that field and you could end up with "Acura", "acura", "acira", "acra", etc.  You would need to add a bunch of program logic to correct or track different variations in spelling of the same brand.  If you have a separate CarBrand model, it is much easier to correct typos or mistakes like that and it is literally impossible to duplicate data if you put a unique constraint on the CarBrand.name field.

Comment: By the way, please don't forget to mark my response as the answer if you think it was good enough.

Comment: Here's an article on database normalization if you're interested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would indicate that by defining a `__unicode__` method on your Car model.  The ModelChoiceField should build out the option names by doing something like `unicode(obj)` for each obj in the specified queryset.  More on that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__

Comment: Actually, that is why you suggested to create a separate model for "CarBrand" model. Tha was a very good point.